# Correct format of an Return-Path header

Tags: email, sendmail, return-path, tmail

My application uses *sendmail* to send outbound email.  I set the 'From:' address using the following format:

```
Fred Dibnah <fred@dibnah.com>
```

I'm also setting the **Reply-To** and **Return-Path** headers using the exact same format.

This seems to work in the vast majority of cases but I have seen at least one instance in which this fails, namely when the name part of the above string contains a period (full stop):

```
Fred Dibnah, Inc. <fred@dibnah.com>
```

This fails deep inside the **TMail** code (I'm using Ruby) but it seems like a perfectly valid thing to do.

My question is, should I actually be setting the **Return-Path** and **Reply-To** headers using only the email address as opposed to the above Name + Email format?  E.g.

```
fred@dibnah.com
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a situation like this, it is best to turn to the [RFCs.](http://www.lemis.com/email/email-rfc.html)

Upon reading up on your question, it appears as if *You* shouldn't be setting the **Return-Path** value ever. The final destination SMTP server is supposed to be setting this value as it transitions the message to your mailbox (http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2821.html starting at 4.4).

According to http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html the **Reply-To** field can have the following formats

1. local-part "@" domain (fred@dibnah.com for example)
2. display-name  (Fred Dibna  for example)

I would recommend using option 1 as it seems to be the most basic, and you will likely have less issues with that format. In choosing option 1, your **Reply-To** field should look like the following:

```
Reply-To: fred@dibna.com
```

Comment: Read the spec?  No way...   :-)